# DNN redirects to 503 error page instead of a 404 error page

Tags: dotnetnuke

We have got two separate servers running DNN version 9.01.01.

They both are configured the same in IIS with Custom Error Pages turned off.
The web.config is set to:

```
<customErrors mode="off"/>
```

We are trying to test and go to a page which does not exist which should give a 404 Error page but instead, it goes to a 503 Error Page (Service Unavailable). When I look at the DNN Admin Logs it says the that it is trying to go to a 404 error page.

[image]

[image]

I noticed that when I select a non-specified page in the DNN Settings under the Behaviour Tab, it then gives a different error:

[image]

From this information, I suspect it is a DNN 9.1.1 bug?

I found a previous bug which was present in earlier DNN versions:
https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-8611?jql=summary%20~%20%22503%20error*%22%20OR%20description%20~%20%22503%20error*%22%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC

I also found this DNN post:

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/538218/scope/posts/getting-503-error-instead-of-404-page

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @user1447679 I need my manager to update the live DNN website to the latest version, then I will revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded to DNN 9.2.2 and still had the same problem.

I changed the Page Persistence setting to Page instead of Memory and it fixed the problem.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Content/Dnn.Platform/Documentation/Using%20the%20Control%20Panel/Host%20Console/Host%20Settings/Advanced%20Settings/Performance%20Settings/Setting%20Page%20State%20Persistence.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out. Remove any modules from the page that require user/session data. Best way to solve it is to remove all modules from your 404 page and start adding them back to see which one is the culprit.

Comment: I just had this happen last week. I wish I could remember what the problem was with the module...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 404 and 500 pages selected in Site Settings > Behaviour and deleted the pages. I re-created these pages and selected them again. The site will now show a 503 error instead of a 404 error. This is a DNN 9.01.01 bug. Upgrading will probably solve this issue.

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/538218/scope/posts/getting-503-error-instead-of-404-page